# Positioning subheading content without affecting another HTML list

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am making a list with a heading and subheadings. My main list, Home1, is followed by a subheading. How can I exactly position the subheading content without affecting another list?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="testnav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul id="subnav">
                <div style=" float : left; width :70%;" >
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
                </div>
                <div STYLE="float : left; width :30%; height:900px;">
                    Sub Heading Content
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#testnav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    marigin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    width: 900px;
}
#subnav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    marigin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation was really incomprehensible but is slightly better now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding the question, but looking at your markup I see that you have a DIV as a direct descendant of a UL. Only LI elements can be children of UL.

```
<ul id="subnav">
  <div style=" float : left; width :70%;" > <!-- THIS DIV CANNOT BE HERE -->
    <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
  </div> <!-- THIS DIV CANNOT BE HERE -->
  <div STYLE="float : left; width :30%; height:900px;"> <!-- THIS DIV CANNOT BE HERE -->
    Sub Heading Content
  </div> <!-- THIS DIV CANNOT BE HERE -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, ul > div is not valid HTML.

Comment: UL elements should have LI elements as their children.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to solving your problem is making sure your markup is correct as Andy Ford suggested. Secondly, making sure your spelling of the CSS in the code is correct may help.

From what I can decipher from your question, you're trying to make sure that `#subnav` is absolutely positioned relative to `#testnav`.

```
<ul id="testnav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul id="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Heading</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>
</ul>
#testnav, #subnav { list-style:none; padding:0; }
#subnav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```

I am not sure if that's what you want, but generally the first step to figuring out what's going wrong with CSS is to remove every extraneous addition you can.